# HTTP POST-ing both JSON data, and query string values to a web API in dotNet core 3.0

Tags: json, asp.net-core-webapi, model-binding

**Background:**

I'm trying to implement a web API using dotNet core 3.0 so that it would accept a POST-ed payload of JSON data.

I have achieved this, but there is an additional complexity: The system that posts the JSON data provides authentication via an API key which appears on the query string. (Actually - it provides 3 query string values: the api key, a timestamp, and a MAC hash, based on a shared secret, of the first two values.)

(I would rather it appeared in the HTTP header as an X-Api-Key value, as I have implemented security via this method previously - but I don't get a choice)

The JSON data is actually a list of objects of the same type, so the binding on the controller method looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    public IActionResult AddMyStuffBatches(List<MyStuffBatch> batches)
```

The authentication values that appear on the query string are really nothing to do with the model - they are unrelated to the data uploaded by the process. So as such, they should not appear in the `batches` list or as a property of a specific instance of `MyStuffBatch`.

**So the question is:** How do I design a controller that deals with the authentication API key details passed on the query string, whilst (assuming a valid API key etc. is passed) still processing the JSON payload as before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `[FromQuery]` on your post action to bind parameters from query string, for example:

Url:

```
POST https://localhost:5001/weatherforecast?timestamp=2019-11-06T09:27:36.000Z&apiKey=secretkey
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
public IActionResult AddMyStuffBatches(List<MyStuffBatch> batches,[FromQuery] string timestamp, [FromQuery] string apiKey)
```

Comment: This seems to work! Thanks. I didn't realize I could use annotations like `[FromQuery]` when I had annotated the controller class with `[ApiController]`.